# How can I set up a Stripe prebuilt page that allows users to select multiple options?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Next.js and I sell packs of credits. $10 for 10 credits, $20 for 30 credits and so on. I want a prebuilt Stripe page where the users can select whichever they want. Is that possible with Stripe Checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot present a menu of options like you describe *within* a Checkout session, but you could for example use a [Pricing Table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table) to present the purchase options to a customer which then redirects to Checkout for the chosen item.

Within Checkout, you might want to also leverage [cross-sells](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/cross-sells) to have customers "add on" to a lower tier package to upgrade to a higher tier, effectively.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a prebuilt "page" as such but You can integrate [Pricing Table](https://stripe.com/docs/no-code/pricing-table) for this. It will allow you to display pricing information and it also integrates seamlessly with Checkout.